# Complex group regex pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have developed regex pattern to parse bibliography in scientific articles. We use AMA citation style, for journal citations it is can look like this:

```
"Nielsen MK, Neergaard MA, Jensen AB, Bro F, Guldin MB. Psychological distress, health, and socio-economic factors in caregivers of terminally ill patients: a nationwide population-based cohort study. Support Care Cancer. 2016; 24(7): 3057-3067."
```

or without issue number:

```
"Nielsen MK, Neergaard MA, Jensen AB, Bro F, Guldin MB. Psychological distress, health, and socio-economic factors in caregivers of terminally ill patients: a nationwide population-based cohort study. Support Care Cancer. 2016; 24: 3057-3067."
```

or with only first page (electronic number).

```
"Nielsen MK, Neergaard MA, Jensen AB, Bro F, Guldin MB. Psychological distress, health, and socio-economic factors in caregivers of terminally ill patients: a nationwide population-based cohort study. Support Care Cancer. 2016; 24(7): 3057."
```

or simply with only volume number (if ahead of print):

```
"Nielsen MK, Neergaard MA, Jensen AB, Bro F, Guldin MB. Psychological distress, health, and socio-economic factors in caregivers of terminally ill patients: a nationwide population-based cohort study. Support Care Cancer. 2016; 24."
```

My pattern matches all this situations and groups all the data (escape with 2 slashes because of Java):

```
(.*?)\\.(.*?)\\.(.*?)(?<year>\\d+)\\s*?;?\\s*?(?:(?<volume>\\d+))?(?:\\((?<issue>\\d+)\\))?\\s*?(?::\\s*?(?<fpage>\\d+|[A-Za-z]+\\d+))?(?:[\\-\\–](?<lpage>\\d+))?\\.
```

The problem is that authors consistently put whitespace between first and last page number. I think maybe this pattern can be changed also to match this?

```
"Nielsen MK, Neergaard MA, Jensen AB, Bro F, Guldin MB. Psychological distress, health, and socio-economic factors in caregivers of terminally ill patients: a nationwide population-based cohort study. Support Care Cancer. 2016; 24(7): 3057 - 3067."
```

here is an [example](https://regex101.com/r/qGYXTU/1), where can be seen that pattern matches this incorrectly.

Comment: Doesn't work replacing `[\\-\\–]` near the end with something like `(?:\\-|\\–| \\- | \\– )` ?

Comment: Nope. It all goes to group 3.

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/rUhFs0/1 .. just been playing around.

Comment: Also may be used. But not ideal match for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Proper regex is

```
(.*?)\.(.*?)\.(.*?)(?<year>\d+)\s*?;?\s*?(?:(?<volume>\d+))?(?:\((?<issue>\d+)\))?\s*?(?::\s*?(?<fpage>\d+|[A-Za-z]+\d+))?(?:[ ]*[\-|\–][ ]*(?<lpage>\d+))?\.
```

This one https://regex101.com/r/RAdNgb/2 fixes your issue. please check it.

Comment: An answer needs to be self-contained.  If your link ever becomes stale, your answer is effectively useless.  Include your solution in the answer itself.

Comment: @VGR : Done buddy !!

Comment: Yep. It works. Forgot that I can put space inside the square brackets to match the optional whitespace :)